# couldn't use error style of twitter bootsrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the "input with error" styling 
as appear here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

and after it a custom css only

(relevant row is 722

```
form .clearfix.error > label, form .clearfix.error .help-block, form .clearfix.error .help-inline {
  color: #b94a48;
}
```

)

My markup:

```
<div id="new_folder_name_div" class="clearfix error">
                    <label for="new_folder_name">Name&nbsp</label>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="medium error" id="folder_name" size="15" type="text" />
                        <span>*</span>
                    </div>
```

An image:

[image]

but I see with Chrome console the input element isn't matched with the above css role.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual input is the next line down. Note that the containing div with classes "clearfix error" is required.

```
form .clearfix.error input, form .clearfix.error textarea {
    color: #B94A48;
    border-color: #EE5F5B;
}

<div class="clearfix error">
    <div class="input">
      <input class="xlarge error" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: got the bootsrap.css as is. still doen't color my input with red

Comment: Your input needs to be inside a form, is it? works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/QHNFr/2/

Comment: btw, how do you add resources to jsfiddle which are not online? where do you host them?

Comment: The twitter bootstrap css is online (taken from the hotlink the css section in the top of the docs) http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('#folder_name').closest('.clearfix error').addClass('error');
```